# Updating BLOB Columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, blob

I have table *blobtable* which has a BLOB column *blobcol*.
A user updated the table using a command similar to this:

```
UPDATE BLOBTABLE
SET BLOBCOL=BFILENAME('directory/subdirectory', 'filename.txt')
WHERE ROWID='ROWIDVALUE';
```

Note that the file *filename.txt* existed in the directory before this update was performed.

Now, the user is saying that when they select from blobtable (using PL/SQL developer), blobcol contains "Value Error" for this row.  Normally, blobcol contains the value "BFILE".  Out of curiosity, I tried selecting the same record in SQL*Plus and I get the following value for blobcol:

*bfilename(directory/subdirectory', 'filename.txt')*

I'm not very familiar with BLOBs and how they work, so my questions are:

1. Did the user update the blobcol properly?
2. What could cause the "Value Error" and how can this be corrected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not how you load a `BLOB` field. `BFILENAME` returns a `BFILE` locator, and `BFILE` data is not stored in the database, but in files outside of but accessible to the database.

The above command would not even succeed if BLOBCOL is really of `BLOB` type, you would get the below error:

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BLOB got FILE`

Another mistake is that `BFILENAME` expects the name of a directory database object, not a directory path on the filesystem.

If you want to update a `BLOB` field with the contents of a file, this is how you do that:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY MY_DIR AS '/directory/subdirectory';

DECLARE
  src_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'filename.txt');
  dest_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT BLOBCOL into dest_blob FROM BLOBTABLE WHERE ROWID = 'ROWIDVALUE';

  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_blob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_bfile,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_bfile) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_lob);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

As to what caused the `Value Error` message, we do not know your table structure nor the exact method how it was loaded, but it was done with an inappropriate method, I think.

Finally, if your file really is a plain text file (just guessing because of `.txt`), then you could store that in a `CLOB` instead of `BLOB`.

Comment: The column was actually BFILE and not BLOB.  My mistake.  The root issue was that the directory object was incorrect.  Thanks for the detailed answer.